# Parsing JSON in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, json

I am trying to parse the JSON at this URL:

> http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=canada&sensor=false

in Objective-C. I'm trying to get the northeast latitude under "bounds", and this is the code I've written to try and do that (`feed` is an `NSDictionary` object):

```
NSArray *results = [feed objectForKey:@"results"];
NSDictionary *firstResult = [results objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *geometry = [firstResult objectForKey:@"geometry"];
NSDictionary *firstGeo = [geometry objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *bounds = [firstGeo objectForKey:@"bounds"];
NSDictionary *northeast = [bounds objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *neLat = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[northeast objectForKey:@"lat"]];
```

Even though it compiles fine and the JSON data is valid, when I run it I get this error:

> [__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa672390
>   2012-02-24 01:32:06.321 Geo[570:11603] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa672390'

I don't know why this is happening, as I successfully got `long_name` before… any help is greatly appreciated :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `geometry` and `bounds` are already dictionaries.

```
     "geometry" : {    // <-- a dictionary!
        "bounds" : {   // <-- also a dictionary!
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 83.1150610,
              "lng" : -52.62040200000001
           },
```

So you should write

```
NSDictionary *geometry = [firstResult objectForKey:@"geometry"];
NSDictionary *bounds = [geometry objectForKey:@"bounds"];
NSDictionary *northeast = [bounds objectForKey:@"northeast"];
```

Comment: don't forget about `-valueForKeyPath:`: `[ firstResult valueForKeyPath:@"geometry.bounds.northeast" ]`

Comment: @nielsbot: Note that `-valueForKeyPath:` is extremely inefficient.

Comment: Hey thanks! This worked perfectly! Just a question though… when I got the `long_name`, I alternated between `NSArray`s and `NSDictionary`s, (and that worked), why didn't that work here? (and how do I know which to use in future circumstances?)

Comment: @user1226490: If you see a `[` in the JSON, it is an NSArray. If you see a `{`, it is an NSDictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following statement.

```
NSArray *geometry = [firstResult objectForKey:@"geometry"];
```

It seems for the `geometry`, it does not return NSArray. It returns `NSDictionary`